# Onclick URL extender

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, syntax, onclick

My problem resides within the syntax of the onclick funtion.

My URL for the page I'm working on(Simplified for obvious reasons):

www.mytestsite.com/**tier-1**/**tier-2**.html

My code right now:

```
<div onclick="location.href='tier-3.html';">
```

When clicked, it attempts to bring me to a page with a URL of:

www.mytestsite.com/**tier-1**/**tier-3**.html

I'd like it to extend the current URL dynamically so it'll bring me to:

www.mytestsite.com/**tier-1**/**tier-2**/**tier-3**.html

Does anyone know if this is possible to do within the onclick function? This is going to be dynamic, so I'm reluctant to do the simple fix of:

```
<div onclick="location.href='tier-2/tier-3.html';">
```

I really appreciate any help anyone offers me!

Comment: how do you know if you have to add `tier-2/` to the url or something else?

Comment: just to check !!! you dont want to use jquery ??

Answer (score 0):

You should not use inline javascript, it's hard to debug to debug and keep things scoped. Just create an event listeners for each  div.
You can set a  topdir variable, that you change to suit your needs.

```
//pure javascript way:
var topdir = "tear2/";
document.getElementById('mydiv').addEventListener("click", function(){
 window.location = topdir + "tier-3.html";
});
document.getElementById('mydiv2').addEventListener("click", function(){
 window.location = topdir + "someotherurl.html";
});

//jquery way:
var topdir = "tear2/";
$('#mydiv').on('click', function(){
window.location = topdir + "tier-3.html";
})
$('#mydiv2').on('click', function(){
window.location = topdir + "someotherurl.html";
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("yourdiv").setAttribute("onclick", "location.href='tier-2/tier-3.html';");
```

**EDIT**

Use global js variables if you wanna increase your "tier" value and extend your url.

Your html:

```
<div onclick="url_update();"></div>
```

Then create your global var and your function:

```
var global_url = "tier-1";
var global_count = 1;

function url_update(){

    global_count++; // increase "tier" value
    global_url = global_url + "/tier-" + global_count;

    // your new global_url will be = "tier-1/tier-2";

    location.href = global_url + ".html";
}
```

I hope it was what you were looking for!

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to add a brief explanation rather than posting a code only answer.

Comment: Usually I do, but I think the code speak for itself. He wants to change the attribute onclick dynamically so I said: try to get the element by id and set the attribute "onclick" with "location.href..."

Comment: Well, this would work. However, 'tier-2' is going to be dynamic. There will be many different cases of this appearing on my website. I'm looking for way to extend the url, keeping in tact what is already there.

As an example, one situation may be that the existing url is mytestsite.com/tier-1/tier-2/tier-3/tier-4.html  And I'd like to extend that to a tier-5 url.

Comment: @DivineChickenwing I edited my answer. Hope it helps!